# Opened a phising email on school email

Tags: email, android, virus, phishing

[image]

Hello I opened this email sent to my school email and I realized it was a phising email.

And now my OCD and anxiety are going haywire. Is it possible I got infected? I did not click on any links. I just opened it.

I tried to change my password but the school system wont let me and their offices are closed. I opened it on my galaxy 9 . Is the phone infected? Will I be safe in connecting it to the school wifi that is connected to the email ? Should I change all my passwords on the apps on my phone??

Comment: you said you didnt click any links.so i am assuming you didnt give any credentials or downloaded anything.So no you cannot be infected just by opening an email.

Answer (score 4):

You weren't the only one who noticed this message had malicious content: Office 365 noticed it, too:

> To help protect your privacy, some content in this message has been blocked. To re-enable the blocked features, **click here**.
>
> To always show content from this sender, **click here**.

Unless you enabled the harmful content or clicked any links on the email, you should be safe. If you clicked something, then it depends: this question doesn't have enough information  to say anything about the harmful content itself. However, you should not try and get this information by clicking anything.

Answer (score 0):

## Your phone is not infected

Unlike with PCs, it is almost impossible to get malware silently running on a (non-rooted) phone by simply opening an email. You can't run software without installing it and you can't do that without showing a full-screen notification asking you to confirm (unless the installing app resides within the '/sys/priv-app' folder, the only relevant one of which is Google Play).

You say you haven't done anything other than open the email, so unless you've highly annoyed a world government of some description, you haven't attracted the attention of anyone able to perform this kind of attack against your phone.